# Why game crashes because low memory on iPad mini but OK on iPad2?

Tags: ios, low-memory, ipad-mini

The game we are developing is crash on iPad mini with IOS 7 because the low memory warning when the game uses about 200MB memory. However, there is more than 100MB free device memory, and the game is OK on iPad2.

Anyone knows what happened on iPad mini? IPad mini's hardware is similar as iPad2, but why there is low memory warning on ipad mini though iPad2 is OK?

Why low memory warning will be sent when the device has lot of free memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've an oversized app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/18_BestPractices/BestPractices.html

I had problems with a 120mb app on iPad 2 but not in an iPhone 5,and I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same on the mini. I think the ios will get uppity if you suddenly increase the amount of memory your app needs as well.

I read somewhere that we should all be aiming for 70mb app sizes (the link above indicates 60) but that can be easier said than done...